# android googlemap is not display in real device

Tags: android, google-maps, genymotion

I used in my genimotion and it display normally, but in my real device it is only while screen :(, I config my code for longtime but it's still not display.

API_Key is right, almost thing is right, I think so because I runed normally in genymotion.

here is my code:

```
package fu.capstone.hemo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import fu.capstone.hemo.R;
import fu.capstone.hemo.activities.HelpPage;
import fu.capstone.hemo.common.CalculateUtills;
import fu.capstone.hemo.dao.ActivityDAO;
import fu.capstone.hemo.dao.MenuActivityDAO;
import fu.capstone.hemo.dao.UserProfileDAO;
import fu.capstone.hemo.vo.ActivitiesEntity;
import fu.capstone.hemo.vo.MenuActivityEntity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SeeGoogleMap extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    Location mlocation = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    LocationListener listen;
    long timeInMills;
    TextView txtTime, txtDistance, txtCaloBurn, txtCountTime, txtMeterDone;
    Calendar cal;
    Button btnStartTime, btnStopTime;
    int profileID;
    MyCount timer;
    List<Location> listLocation;
    float distanceSum = 0;
    MenuActivityEntity menuEntity;
    ProgressBar pro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_google_map);
        listLocation = new ArrayList<Location>();
        txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        btnStartTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
        btnStopTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopTime);
        txtCountTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountTime);
        txtMeterDone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMeterDone);
        pro = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.proActiTime);
        btnStopTime.setClickable(false);
        btnStopTime.setAlpha(0);
        findViewById(R.id.imgBackPress).setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                HelpPage.class));
                    }
                });
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("profileIdShared",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        profileID = prefs.getInt("profileId", 0);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        listen = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listLocation.add(location);
                LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLocation,
                        15));
                String cityName = null;
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        int a = addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                            } else {
                                cityName = cityName + ", "
                                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Vị trí hiện tại")
                        .snippet(cityName).position(lastLocation));

                Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(listLocation.get(
                                listLocation.size() - 1).getLatitude(),
                                listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1)
                                        .getLongitude()),
                                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                        .getLongitude())).width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED));
                float distance = listLocation.get(listLocation.size() - 1)
                        .distanceTo(location);

                distanceSum += distance;
                txtMeterDone.setText(distanceSum + "");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "location changed!" + listLocation.toString(), 2000)
                        .show();
            }
        };
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS: " + mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                +"Wifi: "+ mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                , 3000).show();
        String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        mlocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (mlocation == null) {
             mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
             LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listen);
        }
        else{
            LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(mlocation.getLatitude(),
                    mlocation.getLongitude());
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLocation,
                    15));
        }

        btnStartTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnStartTime.setClickable(false);
                btnStartTime.setAlpha((float) 0.0);
                btnStopTime.setClickable(true);
                btnStopTime.setAlpha(1);
                timer = new MyCount(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 30 * 60 * 1000, 1000);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listen);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        btnStopTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btnStartTime.setClickable(true);
                btnStartTime.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listen);
                try {
                    timer.cancel();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                btnStopTime.setAlpha(0);
                btnStopTime.setClickable(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        long timee;
        int count = 0;
        int ho = 0, mi = 0, se = 0;
        String ho1 = "", mi1 = "", se1 = "";

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            timee = millisInFuture;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txtTime.setText("Hoàn thÀNH!");
            txtMeterDone.setText("00:00:00");
            this.cancel();
            // Use Intent to Navigate from this activity to another
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            count++;
            if (count < 10) {
                se1 = "0" + count;
            } else {
                se1 = "" + count;
            }
            if (count > 60) {
                mi += 1;

            }
            if (mi < 10) {
                mi1 = "0" + mi;
            } else {
                mi1 = "" + mi;
            }
            if (mi > 60) {
                ho += 1;
            }
            ho1 = "0" + ho;
            txtCountTime.setText(ho1 + ":" + mi1 + ":" + se1);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listen);
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toMinutes(millis)));
            txtTime.setText(hms);
            pro.setProgress(count);

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listen);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listen);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

and here is my manifast :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fu.capstone.hemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
            android:name="fu.capstone.hemo.SeeGoogleMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_see_google_map" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDdkM-X-ZCQm8qq3CddIViFzTzHVaeOZtQ" />
    </application>
```

SOLVED : thanks ## Arun Antoney##, only export signed APK then register SHA-1 in last of step that is show, it run like a chamed :3

Comment: Why use `SupportMapFragment` when min sdk is 14?

Comment: I think because OF using countdowntimer is require min API lv 14, i will check it now.
 And nice to see you again, Raghunandan :)

Comment: Hai friend now the app is in debug mode or in build mode??

Comment: has nothing to do with that

Comment: :(. my phone can not connect to run in eclipse, so I only generate to APK file and put it to my phone, and run it :(. 
 I will update full code, please help me

Comment: if the api created using debug.keystore it will show map only in debug mode

Comment: ahhhh , may be it is real answer.My API ke created using debyg.keystore, so how can i do to get my map display in my android phone? Thanks you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create a **new api key** using your **project keystore file** and package name.And try,because  the api created using **debug.keystore**  will show map only in debug mode

Comment: thanks you, but where is my  project keystore file :(

Comment: when u export your project you are creating the keystore file,pls check the file location where u stored.Also make sure while naming keystore file u need to give the extension yourself i.e file.keystore

Comment: have you got the o/p let me know

Comment: -1 for advicing creation of new key instead of just adding your production certificate to current maps key

Comment: I goting I/O exception when export key signed key

i247.photobucket.com/albums/gg129/linhlinhls/Untitled.jpg

Comment: dear Marcin Orlowsky. I do not know how much you know about android. But if you know how to solve my problem, u can help me, but not to report someone, Arun Antoney is good men.

Comment: Have u already created signed apk,if yes then just add the extension to your keystore file

Comment: yes. I just already created signed apk :), Because of keytool password that I typed wrong , then, how will i do next, Arun Antoney :D, how to add the extension to my keystore file?